# SMD inductor soldering tab termination

Tags: inductor, surface-mount

I'm not very expert with SMD components. When I was looking for an inductor I found this [component](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/IHDM1107BBEV120M30?qs=XAiT9M5g4x%252B8WldDprrRlA%3D%3D):

[image]

The termination style is solder tab.  How can this be an SMD inductor when the leads are perpendicular instead of being flat?
How are the leads soldered to the surface and not through hole?

Comment: When I click on your link it takes me to the "Power Inductors - **Leaded**" category. So it's not surface-mount, it's through-hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 1197bb datasheet]

The datasheet shows it as a through-hole model.  Solder tab isn't a strictly-SMD designation like J-lead or no-lead.  Not the case here, but it's also very possible for big component distributors to mis-categorize parts or for the manufacturer to use a picture that doesn't match the exact configuration of the part.  The dimensioned drawings on the datasheet are the truth, everything else is suspect.  Screen capture from [the datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/427/ihdm_1107bb_x0-2891804.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It's not an SMD part.  The [datasheet on the linked page](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/427/ihdm_1107bb_x0-2891804.pdf) has this to say:

[image]

"High Current, Through-Hole Inductor,
Edge-Wound Series" - definitely not SMD.

Comment: Thank you for the response, does that mean solder tab termination is similar to radial? As in they will both be through hole components?

Comment: Yes, radial and solder tab are both through hole types.